# Combine Multiple Excel Files, Pull in File Name, Filter File Name with Regex, Add Filtered File Name into New Column

Tags: excel, regex, powershell

I'm trying to combine multiple excel files after adding a new column whose contents can be derived from the file name. The new column is a license number and is the CCL18-000000x number in the file name. All files follow the same data structure and all have standard file names in the following pattern:

```
Metrc-California-CCL18-0000001-Packages-Active.xlsx
Metrc-California-CCL18-0000002-Packages-Active.xlsx
Metrc-California-CCL18-0000003-Packages-Active.xlsx
....
Metrc-California-CCL18-000000x-Packages-Active.xlsx
```

I have a routine that I've modified to combine all these files as is. This is the routine I'm using:

```
#Get a list of files to copy from
$Files = GCI 'C:\Users\User1\Downloads' | ?{$_.Extension -Match "xlsx?"} | select -ExpandProperty FullName

#Launch Excel, and make it do as its told (supress confirmations)
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

#Open up a new workbook
$Dest = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

#Loop through files, opening each, selecting the Used range, and only grabbing the first 6 columns of it. 
# Then find next available row on the destination worksheet and paste the data
ForEach($File in $Files){
    $Source = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File,$true,$true)
    If(($Dest.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Count -eq 1) -and ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2))){ #If there is only 1 used cell and it is blank select A1
        [void]$source.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","I$(($Source.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)").Copy()
        [void]$Dest.Activate()
        [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select()
    }Else{ #If there is data go to the next empty row and select Column A
        [void]$source.ActiveSheet.Range("A2","I$(($Source.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)").Copy()
        [void]$Dest.Activate()
        [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A$(($Dest.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -last 1).row+1)").Select()
    }
    [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Paste()
    $Source.Close()
}
$Dest.SaveAs("C:\Users\User1\Downloads\Merged.xlsx",51)
$Dest.close()
$Excel.Quit()
```

My goal is to pull the file name in, filter it down to the license number (CCL18-0000001) with a regular expression, and then insert the filtered license number into a new column for the whole used range. Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Thanks

Comment: Why the VBA tag and not Powershell (assuming that's what that is..) ?

Comment: Which part do you need help with? The RegEx? I don't even see where you are doing RegEx.

Comment: Sorry, it is a powershell routine. Messed up the tags.

Comment: I need help figuring out how to grab the filename and get it into the excel file on each line  with data in it. The regex for the filename is just one part but would love help with that as well.